# "Reverse" the x(integer) giving y=0 of a trigonometric graph

Tags: math, graph, trigonometry

**Hello**

The graph for y=sin(x*pi/5)*2*sin(x*pi4) looks like this:

[image]

Some y=0 are 4,5,8,10,12,15,16

Is there a **general** technique (imagine the equation having more components) - that can give us a new equation where the integers that satisfy y(x)=0 will be an arbitrary nonzero number, and the integers with a nonzero numbers will be set to zero?

In python I can easily find the nonzero with this code:

```
#for 100 first integers

for i < 100
    if y != 0:
        print x
    1 += 1
```

But I wonder if this can be done mathematically - preferably as a trigonometric function.

Comment: `1 += 1` <- that's going to work out well !

Comment: Sorry. I meant of course "i += 1". Intention of the code: print all integers of x with a non-zero y-value.